# not able to display question mark icon in chrome using bootstrap css

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

> i need to display the question mark icon using bootstrap CSS in firefox can anybody help me
>   to solve this issue.i tried with the bootstrap css code its coming fine in chrome but not in firefox

Answer (score 0):

Try using the HTML Number `&#63;`

http://www.ascii-code.com/

Comment: where to add this html number i have the bootstrap css included in my project i m adding this bootsrap css with gwt.

Comment: i am using this code to display the question mark <i class="icon-li icon-question"></i> its coming fine in chrome but not in firefox

Comment: have you tried replacing `question` in `icon-li icon-question` with `&#63;` to see if that does anything?

Comment: yah tried nothing is coming,the problem is the above code is working fine in chrome but not in firefox.i have added the bootstrap css for the icon-question mark